# Pre-downloading SmoothStreaming asset

Tags: asynchronous, web, sequential

I'm building a pre-downloader for SmoothStreaming assets whereby we retrieve the client manifest, extract bitrates for video and audio, iterate through the fragment definitions via XDocument and then (here's where I'm stuck) request the fragments SEQUENTIALLY from the server.  The idea is to mimic a media element and cache the fragments on the client for offline use.  All of the parsing and uri-building is fine.  I'm stuck on the threading and async aspects of making the web calls.

Currently I have (much abbreviated):

```
   client = new WebClient();
   client.OpenReadCompleted += GetClientManifest;
```

And in GetClientManifest:

```
  using (Stream str = e.Result)
            {
             // I have the manifest. I need to parse it and make the fragment calls
            }
```

My first block (sorry for being thick) is that inside GetClientManifest, I'm in a callback, so how do I start doing the parsing and fragment getting inside an open web request?
Is it simply a question of spinning up a new web client?

I'm also having trouble thinking of an efficient way to make the fragment requests.  They must be in strict sequential order, alternating between video fragment and audio fragment.

So I'm looking for something like:

```
foreach (var urlPair in fragmentList) 
//urlPair is the audio and video urls for the current fragment
{
     //get the video fragment and save it
     //get the audio fragment and save it
}
```

But this loop has to happen outside of (after completion of) GetClientManifest, no?
Bear in mind this is called from a Silverlight (out of browser) client.  For some reason I couldn't get async await to work (using Task).

Thanks in advance and bon weekend 
Mark D

Comment: I have a version of this working using BackgroundWorker.  So I get the client manifest and pass it to a worker method, which iterates through the fragment info list asynchrojously, using thread.sleep to wait for each request to complete.  TODO - handle timeouts and exceptions.  I've just realised  the cached list of urls and fragments doesn't have to be stored sequentially.  It's a simple look-up.  When Silverlight plays the asset, it works through the manifest, building the url for each fragment and then checks the local cache to see if we already have that chunk.  Simply marvellous.